# Update view with SwiftData without a direct query

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have a one-to-many relationship in between my models `Class` ans `Student`. As I would like to display all the students that belong to a class, I cannot easily do that with a `@Query`. Therefore, my code looks like

```swift
struct ClassView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    var class: Class

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(class.students!.sorted { $0.lastName < $1.lastName })
            { student in
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    func addStudent() {
        let newStudent = Student()
        modelContext.insert(newStudent)
        newStudent.class = self.class
    }
}
```

This view also has some code that calls `addStudent` when a button is pressed. Unfortunately, unlike an array of students given back with `@Query`, the view does not get any update when we add a student to the Class.

Is it the right way to get the students that belong to the class? (I'm a bit skeptical as I cannot find a solution with a `@Query`)

What can I do to trigger an update of the View when I add a new student? If there any method I can call just after adding the new student to the class?

Comment: Doesn’t the class already have a reference to the students?

Comment: Yes you should do something like `ForEach(class.students) ...`

Comment: The problem is that if I do so, I have no way of sorting the students the way I want, no? I need to sort them in alphabetical order.

Comment: The first 2 comments made me update the question as the ordering was not explained in the first version of the question.

Comment: You can just use the regular sort methods that come with an array

Comment: @lorem ipsum : Thanks, but if I use `ForEach(class.students!.sorted { $0.lastName < $1.lastName })`, I still don't get any update when I add a new student.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : It does not make a difference if I declare it as `@State` : I don't have any automatic update of the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's the `Class` property you are showing in the view you need to update it with the new student rather than the other way around.

So replace `newStudent.class = self.class` with

```
class.students.append(newStudent)
```

and the view will update with the new `Student`

*Hopefully this is some kind of bug so that when it's fixed it won't matter which end of the relationship we update*

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I thought that the `append` method was called in the background as the `@Relationship` was properly set in the `@Model` classes. I also agree that it is also a bug, but your fix is welcome.